# How to load the saved date value (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) with Antd DatePicker in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, antd

Using AntDesign datepicker to build a project.

```
<DatePicker
  value={moment(item.remarkValue)}
  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
  showTime={{ defaultValue: moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss') }}
  showTime={{ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }}
 placeholder="请选择生效日期"
/>
```

I found that i can select the time and save it. But when I refresh the page and querying the server, got the data from server, the `item.value` is `2019-12-05 08:04:00` but the `DatePicker` shows empty like this:

[image]

So, how can i load the date string with format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) with antd DatePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It even seems that after giving a **value** attribute to DatePicker, the user is unable to reselect a new date and time. So, a feasible solution would be.

```
defaultValue={item.remarkValue?moment(item.remarkValue,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"):null}
```

You could try [here](https://codepen.io/ekas93/pen/YzPpOJG) for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems below code gives invalid moment object as there is no proper format provided in moment() and this datetime string is not recognized by moment itself.

```
value={moment(item.remarkValue)}
```

Try below code

```
value={item.remarkValue?moment(item.remarkValue,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"):null}
```

Comment: I tried it in `getFieldDecorator` 's `initialValue` and the `DatePicker` 's `value` . It doesn't work

Comment: Test the datepicker component by setting value={moment()} only